# How can I copy a table into a new one, with adding new columns?

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the query I'm trying to use:

```
CREATE TABLE A_workers
  AS (SELECT * FROM T_workers, ArchiveTime datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW());
```

I want to copy the T_workers table into A_workers with adding a new column, which holds the date of the archivation (so the time of the copying). The problem is, I have no idea have to add a new extra column, don't know where to put it in the query. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create table a_workers
as
select t.*, sysdate archivetime from t_workers t;
```

Comment: thanks, works properly :) just changed the last a_workers to t_workers

Comment: Opps. Let me fix that typo. You may want to now ALTER the table to add constraints, such as NOT NULL, and defaults if necessary

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE A_workers AS
SELECT col1, col2, col3, SYSDATE AS ArchiveTime
FROM T_workers
```

Comment: ora-00923 from keyword not found where expected :/

Comment: @dmbdnr List out all columns explicitly.